# Value counts and drop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame named "autos" and column named "brand". I have to find top 5% most common brands and drop others.

This is my code and it doesn't drop values but sets them to NaN. How do I solve this?

```
autos["brand"] = autos["brand"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1) >= 5
```

Comment: it would be best to provide a clear example of your input for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mask=autos["brand"].map(autos["brand"].value_counts(normalize=True)).mul(100).round(1) >= 5
df = autos[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
keep = autos["brand"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1) >= 5

out = autos[autos['brand'].isin(keep[keep].index)]
```

###### Timing comparison

One 1M rows with 100 brands

```
# this solution
7.57 ms ± 92.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# map
11.7 ms ± 345 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I didn't post all the tests, but let me rephrase: "*at least 50% faster for 1M rows, 100 brands*", the ratio gets higher when the size increases

Comment: thanks. Value of answer should be increased if add test data.